# How Do I Store Nullable values and Iterate Through Them?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, vb.net, asp.net-web-api

Thanks for taking a moment. I have a url . I'm trying to build the querystring parameters from these nullable input parameters you see below. I'm thinking what I need to do is store the nullable parameters into some type of generic list and then if the given value of the parameter is not null, append it to the url.  So for example, If they supply the  **string? state** a value of **'OH'**  my url would look like (http://www.thiscoolsiteJas.com/api/v1/moratorium?state=OH). How do I do this ? Any advice or direction would be greatly appreciated. - Jason

```
 public  GetMoratoriums(string? state, int? system, DateTime? inEffectOn, bool? expired, int? reason) {
       //How do I build this with parameters  using the input parameters??
        string url = http://www.thiscoolsiteJas.com/api/v1/moratorium?";
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sure there is a better way to do it but this is how I would handle it.

```
string url = http://www.thiscoolsiteJas.com/api/v1/moratorium?";

var queryStringParams = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();

if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(state))
   {
       queryStringParams.Add("state",state);
   }
etc...

var newUrl = new Uri(QueryHelpers.AddQueryString(url, queryStringParams));
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
var queryStrings = new List<string>();

if (state.HasValue) { queryStrings.Add($"state={state.Value}"); }
if (system.HasValue) { queryStrings.Add($"system={system.Value}"); }
if (inEffectOn.HasValue) { queryStrings.Add($"inEffectOn={inEffectOn.Value}"); }
if (expired.HasValue) { queryStrings.Add($"expired={expired.Value}"); }
if (reason.HasValue) { queryStrings.Add($"reason={reason.Value}"); }

var result = @"http://www.thiscoolsiteJas.com/api/v1/moratorium";
if (queryStrings.Any()) { result += $"?{String.Join("&", queryStrings)}"; }
return result;
```

Comment: Note: You probably want to specify a format for the string representation of the date value. Other then that, it's a solid answer (though can still be slightly improved (in terms of readability) using a local function for the condition and adding to the list, but that's really not that important).

Answer (score 0):

Object oriented approach ;).

```
public class Parameter
{
    private readonly string _name;

    private readonly object _value;

    public Parameter(string name, object value)
    {
        _name = name;
        _value = value;
    }

    public string ForQuery()
    {
        return _value == null ? null : $"{_name}={_value}";
    }
}
```

Usage

```
string? state = "new_state";
int? system = 1;
DateTime? inEffectOn = default;
bool? expired = default;

var parameters = new[]
{
    new QueryParameter("state", state),
    new QueryParameter("system", system),
    new QueryParameter("inEffectOn", inEffectOn),
    new QueryParameter("expired", expired),
};

var queryParameters = parameters.Select(p => p.ForQuery()).Where(p => p != null);
var query = string.Join("&", queryParameters);
```

For example instead of passing long list of parameters you can pass a collection of value of type `QueryParameter` and build query.

With extension method

```
public static string AppendTo(this IEnumerable<QueryParameter> parameters, string baseUrl) 
{
    return parameters
        .Select(p => p.ForQuery())
        .Where(p => p != null)
        .Aggregate(
            new StringBuilder(baseUrl),
            (builder, p) => builder.Append(p).Append("&"),
            (builder) => 
            {
                if (builder.Length > 0)
                {
                    builder.Insert(0, "?");
                    builder.Length -= 1; // remove last "&"
                }
            })
        .ToString();
}
```

Usage

```
var parameters = new[]
{
    new QueryParameter("state", "new"),
    new QueryParameter("system", null),
    new QueryParameter("inEffectOn", null),
    new QueryParameter("expired", false),
};

var url = parameters.AppendTo("http://www.thiscoolsiteJas.com/api/v1/moratorium");
```